# Devices in bridged network don't see eachother

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables, bridge

I have an IoT device with LTE connectivity, 2 ethernet ports and wireless antenna I'd like to use as a LTE router, meaning I would share the LTE connection to wifi and both ethernet ports. It is running full debian image, so it behaves as an ordinary raspberry pi. Wifi and ethernet ports don't have access to the internet by default so to enable internet access I tried connecting the eth0, eth1 an wlan0 interfaces to a new bridge and then routing the packets to wwan0 (LTE interface):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev br0
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set eth1 up
ip link set eth1 master br0
ip link set wlan0 up
ip link set wlan0 master br0
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o wwan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wwan0 -o br0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED  -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also configured `dnsmask.conf` and enabled dhcp for br0 interface. I connected my laptop to the ethernet port and I got access to the internet. The problem is, when I connect a second computer to the eth port or wifi, they all get IPs in the assigned range (in this case 192.168.2.100 - 192.168.2.200) but I cannot ping from one connected computer to another. I suspected that the iptabels commands do something to interfere with the inner traffic, so I tried to add wwan0 interface to the bridge (after deleting the iptables rules) but it threw an error:

```
ip link set wwan0 master br0
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Can the device itself (I assume it works as a Wi-Fi AP) ping its connected devices?

Comment: Hi, it can, but only if I specfy the correct interface, for example ping -I eth0 192.168.2.114 will ping only the device that is actually connected to eth0 interface, ping 192.168.2.114 will not return anything

Comment: Does `ping -I br0 192.168.2.114` not return anything either? What results do you get from `ip route get 192.168.2.114`?

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip addr` with everything up and running. Are there any other firewall rules?

Comment: What you are describing would not be a problem with iptables, although it might be with ebtables.   (Like iptables but works at the ethernet frame layer).  You might also want to examine your ARP cache ("arp -an") for clues.